# Ignore unsupported stream when converting an avi file to an mkv file using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, matroska

The question [Remux to MKV but add all streams using FFmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15049829/remux-to-mkv-but-add-all-streams-using-ffmpeg) explain how to mux all streams to an MKV file.

However this fails when on of the stream was not supported by FFMPEG.

For instance using the command on an avi files with 2 video streams + a subtitle stream :

```
ffmpeg -y -i filename.avi -map 0 -c copy filename.mkv
```

give the following output:

```
ffmpeg version 2.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug  6 2014 13:32:20 with gcc 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1)
  configuration: --enable-static --disable-shared --disable-asm --disable-doc --disable-devices --disable-network --disable-bsfs --disable-protocols --enable-protocol=file --disable-filters --disable-yasm --enable-pic --disable-iconv
  libavutil      52. 92.100 / 52. 92.100
  libavcodec     55. 69.100 / 55. 69.100
  libavformat    55. 48.100 / 55. 48.100
  libavdevice    55. 13.102 / 55. 13.102
  libavfilter     4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libswscale      2.  6.100 /  2.  6.100
  libswresample   0. 19.100 /  0. 19.100
[avi @ 0x2dd8760] non-interleaved AVI
[avi @ 0x2dd8760] Could not find codec parameters for stream 2 (Unknown: none): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, avi, from 'filename.avi':
  Duration: 00:01:01.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4285 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 720x576, 2140 kb/s, 25.52 fps, 25.50 tbr, 25.52 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : sim0_video_H264_0_
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv420p, 720x576, 2140 kb/s, 25.52 fps, 25.50 tbr, 25.52 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : sim2_video_H264_0_
    Stream #0:2: Unknown: none
Cannot map stream #0:2 - unsupported type.
```

Is there is a way to ignore unsupported streams ?

Comment: You should get a recent build from git master either by compiling or just using a [static build](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html). If the issue persists then please [report a bug](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/); include your command, the complete console output, and a sample input file.

Comment: As the code of https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavformat/avidec.c did not changed, the result will be probably the same. The bugs of ffmpeg are reporting thought trac ? not github issue ?

Comment: Yes, the result may be the same, but it is required to test a current build because development is so active. Bugs should be reported via trac. FFmpeg does not use Github for development (it is just a mirror for the source; though some users erroneously submit patches/pull requests through it).

Answer (score 1):

Debugging ffmpeg show that the avi file contains a subtitle stream that have an empty AVI stream format header.

In such situation [avi_read_header](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.3/avidec_8c_source.html) method doesnot set st->codec->codec_type

```
698      case MKTAG('s', 't', 'r', 'f'):
699          /* stream header */
700          if (!size)
701              break;
```

Next [open_output_file](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/ffmpeg__opt_8c_source.html) print the log and exit without condition.

```
1939      switch (ist->st->codec->codec_type) {
1940          case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO: ost = new_video_stream (o, oc, src_idx); break;
1941          case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO: ost = new_audio_stream (o, oc, src_idx); break;
1942          case AVMEDIA_TYPE_SUBTITLE: ost = new_subtitle_stream (o, oc, src_idx); break;
1943          case AVMEDIA_TYPE_DATA: ost = new_data_stream (o, oc, src_idx); break;
1944          case AVMEDIA_TYPE_ATTACHMENT: ost = new_attachment_stream(o, oc, src_idx); break;
1945          default:
1946              av_log(NULL, AV_LOG_FATAL, "Cannot map stream #%d:%d - unsupported type.\n",
1947                      map->file_index, map->stream_index);
1948              exit_program(1);
1949      }
```

Then supporting AVI file with an empty stream format header need to modify ffmpeg.